# changing case for first and last letter C++

Tags: c++, string

i need ThE FirsT AnD LasT letter of every word to be uppercase and the rest lowercase but function convertFirstAndLastLetter only does the first and last of the sentence.

```
void convertFirstAndLastLetter(char wrd[]) 
{
    size_t last = strlen(wrd) - 1;
    size_t first = 0;

    wrd[first] = toupper(wrd[first]);
    wrd[last] = toupper(wrd[last]);

    for(int i = first + 1 ; i < last - 1; i++)
    {
        wrd[i] = tolower(wrd[i]);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    float val;
    cout << "ent ";
    cin >> val;

    if (val == 4)
    {
        char wrd[256];
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(wrd,256);
        convertFirstAndLastLetter(wrd);
        cout << wrd;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1, use `std::string` not `char[]`.

Comment: You're not passing a 'word' to convertFirstAndLastLetter, but a phrase. You need to identify the spaces ' ' between first.

Comment: IDK my first post ever just looking for some help.

Comment: @Kareem Zaiter The answer you were marked as the best is very bad.

Comment: @vlad i clicked the wrong answer i ment to click retired ninja

Comment: @Kareem Zaiter See my answer.

Comment: @vlad nice ill try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're passing a whole line to your function, so the first and last characters are all that is being changed.

To fix that you need to split the line up into words which could be done by reading a word at a time using `std::cin >> word`, or reading the whole line and then using a `std::stringstream` to split it up.  Both are about the same, but I used a stringstream.

Next, if I'm reading your statement correctly, you want to have the first and last "letter" of each word uppercase and the rest lowercase.  That means we need to find the first and last letter in case there is punctuation before or after the word.

Once the first and last are determined it's easy to uppercase them and lowercase the rest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

void convertFirstAndLastLetter(std::string& word)
{
    if(!word.empty())
    {
        size_t first = 0;
        size_t last = word.size() - 1;
        //Find first alpha character
        while(first < word.size() && !std::isalpha(word[first]))
        {
            ++first;
        }
        //If the position is valid, uppercase it
        if(first < word.size())
        {
            word[first] = static_cast<char>(std::toupper(word[first]));
        }

        //Find last alpha character
        while(last > first && !std::isalpha(word[last]))
        {
            --last;
        }

        //If the position is valid, uppercase it
        if(last > first)
        {
            word[last] = static_cast<char>(std::toupper(word[last]));
        }

        for(size_t i = first + 1; i < word.size() && i < last; ++i)
        {
            if(std::isalpha(word[i]))
            {
                word[i] = static_cast<char>(std::tolower(word[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    float val;
    std::cout << "ent ";
    std::cin >> val;
    std::cin.ignore();

    if(val == 4)
    {
        std::string line;
        if(std::getline(std::cin, line))
        {
            std::string word;
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                convertFirstAndLastLetter(word);
                std::cout << word << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind this will discard any extra spaces at the beginning and end of each line as well as any extra spaces between words.  The way I am printing them out will also add an extra space at the end of each line.  You didn't mention any concern about those things in your question, so I didn't worry about them.  They are all solvable with a little extra effort.

Comment: Thank you very helpful piece if code i would upvote if i had the rep.

Comment: it works on it sown but when try to add to my code after an if statement i have issues

Comment: inline `if (val == 4)`

`{
 std::string line;
    for(;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Type a sentence or exit to finish:\n";
        if(!std::getline(std::cin, line) || line == "exit")
        {
            break;
        }
        std::string word;
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        while(ss >> word)
        {
            convertFirstAndLastLetter(word);
            std::cout << word << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
}
}`

Comment: I changed it to more closely resemble your original code.  The important part is that `cin >> val` leaves a newline character in the input buffer and you need to ignore it before using `getline`.

Comment: compile error  error: variable ‘std::stringstream ss’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: It sounds like you missed `#include <sstream>`.  Here's a [working demo](http://ideone.com/8BuNPS)

Comment: compiles and collects string but no output i have inserted the [full code](http://ideone.com/e.js/YUVAgT") thanks so much for your time so far

Comment: You copied the ` if (val == 4)...` part inside another if.

Comment: it works for the other options.. i'm very new to this

Comment: You'll have to look carefully at the code, you'll see there's a duplicate section under where it is checking for `val == 4`.  If you work on indenting your code consistently it will be very easy to see.

Comment: well i must have been blind, i fixed it (feel dumb..lol)but i stll get no output after entering a sentence ***[latest code](http://ideone.com/e.js/z9OzM7)***

Comment: I would buy you a beer right now if i could... thank you for sharing your time i cant stress how appreciative i am. i have been working on this for 13 straight hours.... I'm a new to programming. any recommended books or resources?

Answer (score 2):

Now with less duplicated code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template<typename It>
void upperFirstAlpha(It begin, It end)
{
  auto first = std::find_if(begin, end, isalpha);
  if (first != end)
    *first = toupper(*first);
}



int main()
{
  for (std::string s; std::cin >> s;) {
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);

    upperFirstAlpha(s.begin(), s.end());
    upperFirstAlpha(s.rbegin(), s.rend());

    std::cout << s << ' ';
  }
}
```

As @Retired Ninja pointed out the first version wouldn't work for punctuation, whether this version is what you are looking for depends on what your input looks like.

Comment: Try it with "My dog, Bob, has fleas.".  If there's punctuation the first and last aren't good enough.  Hard to say if that's important or not without sample input.

Comment: Well true, but anyone who doesn't put a space after punctuation is already wrong anyway :p

Comment: It isn't the spacing, it's that the comma or period is the last character of the word, so the last alphabetic character won't be changed.

Comment: Another good point, I guess my only defence is it works for the limited input provided by OP.

Comment: @RetiredNinja fixed for punctuation, although I guess it still assumes words are separated by whitespace.

Comment: I think that's as close as you're gonna get. :)

Comment: i cant get it to compile

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
void convertFirstAndLastLetter(char wrd[]) 
{
    size_t last = strlen(wrd) - 1;
    size_t first = 0;

    wrd[first] = toupper(wrd[first]);
    wrd[last] = toupper(wrd[last]);

    for(int i = first + 1 ; i < last - 1; i++)
    {
        wrd[i] = tolower(wrd[i]);
    }
}
```

is wrong. For example if character array is empty that is it has only the terminating zero then expression `strlen(wrd) - 1` will give you the maximum value for an object of type `size_t` and in the next statement

```
    wrd[last] = toupper(wrd[last]);
```

you will try to change memory beyond the array.

Also if you use standard function `strlen` then you have to include header `<cstring>`.

In fact there is no any need to use function strlen. The code can be written simpler

```
#include <cctype>

//...

void convertFirstAndLastLetter( char wrd[] ) 
{
    if ( *wrd )
    {
        *wrd = std::toupper( *wrd );

        if ( *++wrd )
        {
            while ( *( wrd + 1 ) )
            {
                *wrd = std::tolower( *wrd );
                ++wrd;
            }
            *wrd = std::toupper( *wrd );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If used with his other code this will still only uppercase the first and last character of the whole line, not each word.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void convertFirstAndLastLetter(char wrd[]) 
{
    size_t last = strlen(wrd) - 1;
    size_t first = 0;

    wrd[first] = toupper(wrd[first]);
    wrd[last] = toupper(wrd[last]);

    for(int i = first + 1 ; i < last; i++)
    {
        wrd[i] = tolower(wrd[i]);
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float val;
    cout << "ent ";
    cin >> val;

    if (val == 4)
    {
       char wrd[256];
       cin.ignore();
       cin.getline(wrd,256);
       convertFirstAndLastLetter(wrd);
       cout << wrd;

       return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: _tchar is a macro defined by VC++ compilers [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx), it allow to compile the project in **ascii mode** (with name `main`) or **unicode mode** (with name `wmain`) according if is declared or not the macro `_UNICODE`.

Comment: This has the same problem the original code has, it only affects the first and last character of a line, not of each word.